# Shaded theoremstyle

Tags: environments, theorems

I'm trying to create a theoremstyle whith a shaded background. As I already have a working preamble I'd like to change as less as possible. Previously I defined an own theoremstyle 'selfdefined' which I used for theorems and such.
However as this is not shading my theorems it's not an option anymore.

Now I tried to define a new theoremstyle 'shaded' which is supposed to do this. Unfortunately it's not working the way I want it to work. Instead of using the newly defined theoremstyle it just uses some kind of default theoremstyle.
I hope somebody can help me to fix this (with as few changes as possible and detailed explanations, as I'm pretty much a beginner when it comes to latex).

I'm aware that this is not really a 'minimum working' example, I hope it's still alright.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     % input encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                        % use T1 fonts for font encoding
\usepackage{amsfonts}                           % math font
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{dsfont}                             % math font for number spaces etc.
\usepackage{helvet}                             % sans serif font
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{tikz}                               % for drawings.
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{parskip}                            % vertical space instead of indentation 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}                               % shaded environments
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{selfdefined}
{12pt}% Space above
{12pt}% Space below
{}% Body font \itshape =italian style 
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{}% Punctuation after theorem heading
{\newline}% Space after theorem heading, 0.5em => in gleicher zeile weiter
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.65}
\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=0.5em,
mdframed={
  skipabove=\topsep,
  skipbelow=\topsep,
  hidealllines=true,
  backgroundcolor={shadecolor},
  innerleftmargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt}
]{shaded}

%\swapnumbers
\theoremstyle{shaded}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[definition]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[definition]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}[definition]{Example}
\newtheorem*{algorithm}{Algorithm}

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}[\textbf{Definition 1}]
This is supposed to be a definition in shaded style.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
This is supposed to be a theorem in shaded style.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems; the first two are the main ones:

- You need to load `thmtools` after `amsthm`.
- Since you used `\declaretheoremstyle` for the `shaded` style, you need to define your structures using `\declaretheorem` instead of `\newtheorem`, and pass the `shaded` style as an option to the `style` key instead of using `\theoremstyle`.
- Load `hyperref` in the last place (except some exceptions which can be found elsewhere here).
- Since you are using a KOMA class, instead of loading the `parskip` package you should use the `parskip` class option; in my example I used `parskip=half+` but you can use the desired value (refer to the KOMA users guide to see available options).

The corrected code (adjust the settings according to your needs):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip=half+]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     % input encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                        % use T1 fonts for font encoding
\usepackage{amsfonts}                           % math font
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{dsfont}                             % math font for number spaces etc.
\usepackage{helvet}                             % sans serif font
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{tikz}                               % for drawings.
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}                               % shaded environments
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref} 

\newtheoremstyle{selfdefined}
{12pt}% Space above
{12pt}% Space below
{}% Body font \itshape =italian style 
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{}% Punctuation after theorem heading
{\newline}% Space after theorem heading, 0.5em => in gleicher zeile weiter
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.65}
\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=0.5em,
spaceabove=6pt,
mdframed={
  skipabove=8pt,
  skipbelow=6pt,
  hidealllines=true,
  backgroundcolor={shadecolor},
  innerleftmargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt}
]{shaded}

\declaretheorem[style=shaded,within=section]{definition}
\declaretheorem[style=shaded,sibling=definition]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=shaded,sibling=definition]{corollary}
\declaretheorem[style=shaded,sibling=definition]{conjecture}
\declaretheorem[style=shaded,sibling=definition]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[style=shaded,sibling=definition]{example}
\declaretheorem[style=shaded,numbered=no]{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}
\begin{definition}[\textbf{Definition 1}]
This is supposed a definition in shaded style.
\end{definition}
Some test text
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem in shaded style.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

The result:

Comment: Nice, thank you very much, thats exactly what I was looking for.
Unfortunately a new problem just arose.

Oftentimes the boxes don't really use up the space. So before a pagebreak, theres a space of up to 5-6 lines which is not used by the box, even though the 'insides' would neatly fit in there.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @sblasher You're welcome. Since some code is needed for tests, I think this new problem deserves a new question; the best course of action now would be to open a follow-up question providing a MWE allowing us to reproduce the problem.